# Unity 2.1 - Resolve generic type from non-generic interface?

Tags: generics, interface, unity-container

I'm using Unity (forced into configuration through config file) and I'm kinda stuck right now. The question is rather long, you can skip to **scenario, problem and question**, configuration/code are for reference.

Help is greatly appreciated!

**Configuration**:

```
<register type="IService" mapTo="DefaultService" name="Context1" />
<register type="IService" mapTo="ExtendedService" name="Context2" />

<register type="IManager" mapTo="DefaultManager" name="Context1" />
<register type="IManager" mapTo="ExtendedManager" name="Context1" />
```

**Code**:

```
public interface IService 
{
    void DoSomething();
}

public class DefaultService : IService 
{
    protected IManager Manager { 
        return Container.Resolve<IManager>(ContextBasedName());
    }

    public void DoSomething() {
        Manager.DoSomething();
    }
}

public class ExtendedService : DefaultService 
{

}

public interface IManager  
{
    void DoSomething();
}

public class DefaultManager : IManager 
{
    protected virtual void DoSomething() 
    {
        //Do something default
    }
}

public class ExtendedManager : DefaultManager
{
    protected override void DoSomething() 
    {
        //First do something special

        base.DoSomething(); //then the default
    }
}
```

**Scenario**:

I have two *context* in which the `IService` based types are resolved (*Context1* and *Context2*). `ContextBasedName()` will return the correct string for the actual context.

Inside *Context1*:

```
//Will return DefaultService
var service = Container.Resolve<IService>(ContextBasedName());

service.DoSomething(); //Will eventually call DefaultManager.DoSomething();
```

Inside *Context2*:

```
//Will return ExtendedService
var service = Container.Resolve<IService>(ContextBasedName()); 

service.DoSomething(); //Will eventually call ExtendedManager.DoSomething();
```

## Problem:

The above scenario is fine, however the problem is related to the **code above which doesn't compile**. It doesn't compile because of the `Manager` property definition in the `DefaultService` class:

```
protected IManager Manager { 
    return Container.Resolve<IManager>(ContextBasedName());
}
```

The `IManager` generic type isn't defined at class level. As far as I can see there are only two solutions:

1. Change the `Manager` property to a method and call like so: `.Manager<IManager>()`
2. Add a `IManager` generic type to the class and **somehow** inject the type in Unity resolve method **even though the resolving interface isn't generic**?

## Question:

*Regarding 1: Why isn't it possible to specify generic types on properties?*

*Regarding 2: Is it possible to specify a concrete type in the resolve method **or configuration** even though the interface isn't generic?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use constructor injection and configure the injection of the correct manager for each service?

Currently you are abusing the container as a [service locator](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx).

---

**Update**

If you need to supply runtime values inject a factory for the manager instead of the manager instance.

Comment: But this means I have to configure the constructor value which isn't possible. I'm using a special `ContextBasedName()` method which provides a name at runtime...

Comment: What's wrong with using the container resolve mechanism as factory?

Comment: @Ropstah Did you have a look at the link that is included in my answer?